# Projective planes over non-division rings

Tags: reference-request, projective-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, incidence-geometry

Is there a "right" notion of a projective plane over a general (unital, non-division) ring?

Let me explain what type of object I am looking for. Let $R$ be an arbitrary (not necessarily division) unital ring. Then it is well known hot to define a *projective line* over $R$. Namely, one considers pairs $(a,b) \in R^2$ such that the right ideal that $a$, $b$ generate is the whole ring: $aR + bR = R$. Then one takes the quotient of this subset of $R^2$ by the relation $(a,b) \sim (ua, ub)$, where $u \in R^*$ is an arbitrary unit. The resulting set is called the projective line over $R$. This is a reasonable generalization of a projective line over a field/division ring. In particular, one can define Moebius transformations, cross-ratio etc. For example, when $R = \operatorname{Mat}_2$ (two by two matrices over a field), the condition $aR + bR = R$ says that the rectangular matrix $(a,b)$ is full rank, so the projective line over $\operatorname{Mat}_2$ is the same as the Grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}(2,4)$, or the the set of all lines in $\mathbb P^3$.

In a similar way, one may try to define the projective plane over $R$ as a quotient of the set of triples $(a,b,c) \in R^3$ such that $aR + bR+cR = R$. Again, taking $R = \operatorname{Mat}_2$, we get $\operatorname{Gr}(2,6)$, or lines in $\mathbb P^5$.  The role of lines is played by elements of the dual Grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}(4,6)$, or three-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb P^5$ (as we saw above those are indeed projective lines over the matrix ring). Note that this is not a projective plane in the sense of incidence geometry, because if two lines in $\mathbb P^5$ (i.e. "points") have a point in common, then there are infinitely many three-dimensional subspaces ("lines") incident to both. However, it is a projective plane "generically" and its properties seem to be rather similar to a projective plane over a field. In particular, I would expect that results like the Desargues theorem hold in this setting (assuming all lines are well-defined). Note that this does not contradict the classification of Desarguesian projective planes, because what we are dealing with is not an actual projective plane.

I cannot seem to find anything like this in the literature, beyond the case of division rings, and I would appreciate a reference as well as any thoughts on whether this is or is not a reasonable definition.

Comment: Have you looked at the theory of ternary rings?

Comment: I have, but that seems to be not exactly what I am looking for, because ternary rings describe projective planes (two distinct points define a line etc.) while my example with Grassmannians is "almost" a projective plane (because if two "points" are intersecting lines, then they do not define a unique "line"). Since I asked the question I found a lot of information on this type of "almost" projective planes. They are called "Barbillian planes" and are discussed in the paper Veldkamp, F.D. Projective planes over rings of stable rank 2.